# Huge size of source and compiled files

Tags: mongodb, debian

Just compiled mongodb for debian jessie and have huge size of the source files

```
~/tmp$ du -h ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5 | grep G
1,8G    ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5/build/linux2/normal/mongo/s
1,9G    ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5/build/linux2/normal/mongo/db/storage
1,3G    ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5/build/linux2/normal/mongo/db/exec
1,5G    ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5/build/linux2/normal/mongo/db/query
1,3G    ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5/build/linux2/normal/mongo/db/repl
8,9G    ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5/build/linux2/normal/mongo/db
19G     ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5/build/linux2/normal/mongo
19G     ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5/build/linux2/normal
19G     ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5/build/linux2
19G     ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5/build
21G     ./mongodb-src-r3.0.5
```

Also compiled **mongod** file have a size ~ 400Mb. In wheezy deb version its size about 20Mb

Is it normal?

Comment: Well the odds are on here you have statically linked things that would otherwise be dynamically linked by other builds and/or still have debugging symbols in as well. Asking for a compile recipe is going to be particularly broad. Especially without detailed process of how you performed your build.

Comment: Compiled by official readme for debian https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/building.md#debianubuntu

Comment: that "official" readme (from upstream, not from Debian), doesn't mean much: maybe they prefer static linking over dynamic for whatever obscure reason? (e.g. so they can distribute the binary without having to worry about dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the build folder and mongo seems to be working. 
I think once the executables are created it doesn't use the build folder contents...

Answer (score 0):

That files is stripped (debugging symbols & sections and relocation information are cleaned from files). Try this:

```
strip -sg mongod
```

For me that turn **mongob** from **442.8Mb** to **33.6Mb**.